# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{..}

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, viewmodel, room, dagger

Hola porfavor su ayuda estoy implementando un nuevo proyecto de android con kotlin y estoy usando la librearia Room (Sqlite) Con inyeccion de dependencias (DaggerHoilt) eh estado viendo tutoriales pero hago lo mismo que ellos pero aun asi no me funciona

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LoginUser : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginUserBinding
    private val loginUserViewModel: LoginUserViewModel by viewModels()
    //Metodos onCreate y demas
}
```

tambien tengo el ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginUserViewModel @Inject constructor(private val getUserRepostory : UsuarioLocalRepository) : ViewModel() {
    //Logica Programación
}

class UsuarioLocalRepository @Inject constructor(private val usuarioLocal: IUsuarioLocalDao) {
    //Logica programación
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.loginUser.LoginUser"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

y a lo que intento levantar la aplicación me sale este error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.evalverde.appintegration, PID: 31251
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.evalverde.appintegration/com.evalverde.appintegration.ui.loginUser.LoginUser}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.evalverde.appintegration.ui.loginUser.LoginUser" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~gWf1BI8VZtJnAoRgV6g0_Q==/com.evalverde.appintegration-_Q0ym-niXMDLSYaQ8csCxQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~gWf1BI8VZtJnAoRgV6g0_Q==/com.evalverde.appintegration-_Q0ym-niXMDLSYaQ8csCxQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]

    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4102)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4403)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:104)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2498)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8855)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.evalverde.appintegration.ui.loginUser.LoginUser" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~gWf1BI8VZtJnAoRgV6g0_Q==/com.evalverde.appintegration-_Q0ym-niXMDLSYaQ8csCxQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~gWf1BI8VZtJnAoRgV6g0_Q==/com.evalverde.appintegration-_Q0ym-niXMDLSYaQ8csCxQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at 
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/evalverde/appintegration/ui/loginUser/Hilt_LoginUser;
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.evalverde.appintegration.ui.loginUser.Hilt_LoginUser" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~gWf1BI8VZtJnAoRgV6g0_Q==/com.evalverde.appintegration-_Q0ym-niXMDLSYaQ8csCxQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~gWf1BI8VZtJnAoRgV6g0_Q==/com.evalverde.appintegration-_Q0ym-niXMDLSYaQ8csCxQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tenia problemas con la version entre las librerias

Comment: No olvides proveer más detalles a tu respuesta: pulsa en [edit] y describe cuáles fueron las librerías en conflicto. Lee [answer].